# SQL UPDATE SELECT with WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I want to `UPDATE` a column in a table, but in each row there must go another value dependend on a `WHERE` of another row.

This is how the table looks like.

### BusinessUnitGUID | ClassName | DefaultGUID

```
    5        | PriceList | 349FDAFD34M
    5        | Footer1   | 987IOXG376L
    5        | Header1   | 12WQX954MIO
    7        | PriceList | NULL
    7        | Footer1   | NULL
    7        | Header1   | NULL
```

Results should be this.

### BusinessUnitGUID | ClassName | DefaultGUID

```
    5        | PriceList | 349FDAFD34M
    5        | Footer1   | 987IOXG376L
    5        | Header1   | 12WQX954MIO
    7        | PriceList | 349FDAFD34M
    7        | Footer1   | 987IOXG376L
    7        | Header1   | 12WQX954MIO
```

But this shown query doesn't work, because it returns many rows and so it's not precise.

```
update cSC_BusinessUnit
set defaultguid =
    (
    select defaultguid
    from cSC_BusinessUnit 
    where BusinessUnitGUID = 5
    )
where BusinessUnitGUID = 7
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to do a check on ClassName as well:

```
update b1
set b1.defaultguid =
    (
    select b2.defaultguid
    from cSC_BusinessUnit b2
    where b2.BusinessUnitGUID = 5
        AND b2.ClassName = b1.ClassName
    )
from cSC_BusinessUnit b1
where b1.BusinessUnitGUID = 7
```

Answer (score 6):

Use below short version as well

```
UPDATE  b1
SET     b1.defaultguid = b2.defaultguid
FROM    cSC_BusinessUnit b1
        JOIN
        cSC_BusinessUnit b2
            ON b1.ClassName = b2.ClassName
                And b2.BusinessUnitGUID = 5
WHERE   b1.BusinessUnitGUID = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
update cSC_BusinessUnit t1
set defaultguid =
    (
    select defaultguid
    from cSC_BusinessUnit t2
    where t2.BusinessUnitGUID = 5
    and t1.classname = t2.classname
    )
where BusinessUnitGUID = 7
```

Comment: he is using SQL Server not Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can also set dynamically all the NULL columns like this as long as you have only one occurence of *ClassName* NOT NULL

```
update A
set DefaultGUID =
    (
        select B.DefaultGUID
        from cSC_BusinessUnit B
        where B.ClassName = A.ClassName
        And B.DefaultGUID IS NOT NULL
    )
from cSC_BusinessUnit A
```

Comment: it may cause errors if there is more NOT NULL occurrences of the ClassName

Comment: Indeed, this query is valid only in a context where only one occurence of ClassName has a DefaultGUID NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

**You can try it**

```
update cSC_BusinessUnit a
set a.defaultguid =
    (
    select defaultguid
    from cSC_BusinessUnit b
    where b.BusinessUnitGUID = 5 and b.ClassName = a.ClassName
    )
where a.BusinessUnitGUID = 7
```

Comment: OP is using SQL-server/T-SQL, so `update cSC_BusinessUnit a` is wrong. See the accepted answer for the correct syntax for T-SQL.

Comment: I do it with pl/sql, but i think my idea will use for this issue. thanks u

Answer (score -1):

```
update b1
set b1.defaultguid =
    (
    select b2.defaultguid
    from cSC_BusinessUnit b2
    where b2.BusinessUnitGUID = 5
        AND b2.ClassName = b1.ClassName
    )
from cSC_BusinessUnit b1
where b1.BusinessUnitGUID = 7
```